# Connection closed by remote host after pressing tab for autocomplete

Tags: bash, ssh, putty

I am connecting to a virtual box installation of Ubuntu 15.10 using putty:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.10 (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-22-generic x86_64)
```

If do simply `cd folde [tab]` a window opens

```
"Connection closed by remote host"
```

I have absolutely no idea what is wrong and how to fix this and where this is suddenly coming from.

Edit: new info: this does not seem to happen as root.

---

What I have tried so far:

- Ugraded ubuntu
- Tested both mobaxterm and simple putty
- Putty to any other machine works fine
- It is not due to lack of memory: MemTotal:        9996524 kB, MemFree:         9422540 kB, MemAvailable:    9830548 kB
- Starting another bash using exec bash will make the problem appear less frequently.

---

```
beginner@avalon:~$ sudo tail -100f /var/log/syslog
[sudo] password for beginner:
Dec 21 10:50:44 avalon whoopsie[574]: [10:50:44] online
Dec 21 10:50:48 avalon NetworkManager[623]: <info>  WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Dec 21 10:50:48 avalon NetworkManager[623]: <info>  WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Dec 21 10:50:52 avalon ntpdate[865]: no server suitable for synchronization found
Dec 21 10:51:02 avalon ntpdate[1035]: no server suitable for synchronization found
Dec 21 10:52:08 avalon systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device/start timed out.
Dec 21 10:52:08 avalon systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device.
Dec 21 10:52:08 avalon systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/66341dbb-4e46-4bcd-89ad-9b40aa873fe6.
Dec 21 10:52:08 avalon systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Dec 21 10:52:08 avalon systemd[1]: Startup finished in 9.395s (kernel) + 3min 519ms (userspace) = 3min 9.914s.
Dec 21 10:52:08 avalon systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec 21 11:04:03 avalon systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Dec 21 11:04:03 avalon systemd-tmpfiles[1074]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
Dec 21 11:04:03 avalon systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1]: Created slice user-1001.slice.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 1 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1084]: Reached target Paths.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1084]: Reached target Timers.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1084]: Reached target Sockets.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1084]: Reached target Basic System.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1084]: Reached target Default.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1084]: Startup finished in 26ms.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
Dec 21 11:08:14 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 2 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1001...
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1084]: Reached target Shutdown.
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1084]: Starting Exit the Session...
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1084]: Stopped target Default.
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1084]: Stopped target Basic System.
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1084]: Stopped target Sockets.
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1084]: Stopped target Timers.
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1084]: Stopped target Paths.
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1084]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 1215 (kill).
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1001.
Dec 21 11:08:18 avalon systemd[1]: Removed slice user-1001.slice.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1]: Created slice user-1001.slice.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 3 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1223]: Reached target Sockets.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1223]: Reached target Timers.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1223]: Reached target Paths.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1223]: Reached target Basic System.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1223]: Reached target Default.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1223]: Startup finished in 14ms.
Dec 21 11:08:19 avalon systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
Dec 21 11:08:20 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 4 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1001...
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1223]: Reached target Shutdown.
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1223]: Starting Exit the Session...
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1223]: Stopped target Default.
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1223]: Stopped target Basic System.
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1223]: Stopped target Sockets.
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1223]: Stopped target Timers.
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1223]: Stopped target Paths.
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1223]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 1308 (kill).
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1001.
Dec 21 11:08:39 avalon systemd[1]: Removed slice user-1001.slice.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1]: Created slice user-1001.slice.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 5 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1318]: Reached target Paths.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1318]: Reached target Sockets.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1318]: Reached target Timers.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1318]: Reached target Basic System.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1318]: Reached target Default.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1318]: Startup finished in 17ms.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
Dec 21 11:08:46 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 6 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:09:44 avalon systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device/start timed out.
Dec 21 11:09:44 avalon systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device.
Dec 21 11:09:44 avalon systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/66341dbb-4e46-4bcd-89ad-9b40aa873fe6.
Dec 21 11:09:44 avalon systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Dec 21 11:09:44 avalon systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66341dbb\x2d4e46\x2d4bcd\x2d89ad\x2d9b40aa873fe6.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec 21 11:16:00 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 7 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:16:00 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 8 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:16:21 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 9 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:16:21 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 10 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:17:01 avalon CRON[2542]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 21 11:17:54 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 12 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:17:54 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 13 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:19:42 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 14 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:23:41 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 15 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:24:27 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 16 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:34:47 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 17 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:34:47 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 18 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:35:49 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 19 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:35:49 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 20 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:35:53 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 21 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:35:53 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 22 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:36:23 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 23 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:36:23 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 24 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:40:10 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 25 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:40:10 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 26 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:41:17 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 27 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:41:17 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 28 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:52:24 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 29 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:52:24 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 30 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:52:29 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 31 of user beginner.
Dec 21 11:52:29 avalon systemd[1]: Started Session 32 of user beginner.
```

---

```
$ sudo crontab -e
[sudo] password for beginner:
no crontab for root - using an empty one
```

Check file /etc/crontab:

```
$ sudo less /etc/contab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab

# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

#

Files in cron.daily and cron.hourly

```
raphael@frankfurt:~$ ls /etc/cron*
/etc/crontab

/etc/cron.d:
anacron

/etc/cron.daily:
0anacron  bsdmainutils      logrotate  passwd                  upstart
apport    cracklib-runtime  man-db     popularity-contest
apt       dpkg              mlocate    update-notifier-common

/etc/cron.hourly:
```

---

Diskspace seems fine:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           977M  9.0M  968M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        40G   11G   28G  28% /
tmpfs           4.8G  4.0K  4.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           977M  4.0K  977M   1% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo tail -100f /var/log/syslog` into your post.

Comment: @TungTran do you have an idea what might cause the SIGRTMIN?

Comment: Looks like systemd is flushing your system log. Could you check if you have any cron job running as root?

Comment: `df -h` - how much free space do you have on your hard drive?

Comment: @TungTran Thanks for your help! I think crontab is empty, see edit.

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks for your input! Diskspace seems fine... see edit.

Comment: @Beginner: please show the content of `/etc/crontab` and all files in `/etc/cron.hourly/` and `/etc/cron.daily/` if possible.

Comment: @TungTran should I post the contents of these files?

Comment: Yes please if there is no secret :)

Comment: @TungTran The files exceed the maximal post length. I didn't change any of them. I noticed that autocompletion seems to work fine for user ubuntu though...

Comment: @Beginner OK no problem. I just suspect there might be a cron which is running periodically causing systemd flushing the log.

Answer (score 7):

The problem was the following:

I am sourcing some scripts to setup my environment. One of them contains

```
set -e
```

Everything that causes an error will stop the execution of the bash.

**Lessons learned: never `set -e` in .bashrc.**

---

Edit: 
As NicoMinsk pointed out, it is possible to set -e at the very end of bashrc without any problems.

Comment: I added "set +e" add the end of my .bashrc and it correct my problem ! thanks